# HQ camera is not working with Ubuntu 21.04 on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberrypi, camera

I followed instructions from https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-stream-video-with-raspberry-pi-hq-camera-on-ubuntu-core. I have:

```
start_x=1
```

in my `/boot/firmware/config.txt` file, but `raspistill -t 0` hangs up without displaying the camera preview. How can I fix it? Does Raspberry Pi HQ camera work on 64-bit OS? I've seen some fairly recent posts claiming otherwise.

Also this:

```
paul@pi:~$ snap install picamera-streaming-demo
error: snap "picamera-streaming-demo" is not available on stable for this architecture (arm64) but exists on other architectures (armhf).
```

would indicate that camera works only with 32-bit OS.

Comment: I read it as saying the software does not work. Couple of things. You are not running core software do not know if that is an issue. Also what make and model is the camera?

Comment: @David HQ Raspberry Pi camera.